fileImporter doesn't do anything on another user's device
I searched everywhere on Google and Stackoverflow and couldn't find anything related to this.
So I'm seeing strange behavior on another user's device where the SwiftUI file importer doesn't do anything at all. You can see the behavior here: https://streamable.com/u5grgy
I'm unable to replicate on my own phone or the simulator, and I have url.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource() everywhere I use .fileImporter. Usually though if there's an error file importer will close without importing anything and show a warning to the user, but here it's not doing anything at all.
here is the code in question, just in case:
            .fileImporter(
                isPresented: $showRomDialog,
                allowedContentTypes: [ndsType!],
                allowsMultipleSelection: true
            ) { result in
                do {
                    let urls = try result.get()
                    for url in urls {

                        if url.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource() {
                            ... // process the file here
                        } else {
                            showErrorMessage = true
                            break
                        }
                    }    
                } catch {
                    showErrorMessage = true
                    print(error)
                }      
            }    

Is there a way to figure out what could possibly be happening?
